# AVAudioPlayer for Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

I'm utilizing AVAudioPlayer in MyScene - the main game scene in my Sprite Kit game. I also have an OptionsScene containing 2 buttons. 1 of the buttons is for switching music ON/OFF.

Everything works except pressing the button doesn't instantly turn music ON or OFF. I have to leave the app, double-tap iPhone's Home button & swipe-up the game View to turn it off completely.

Once that is done, I can open the game & the previously selected ON/OFF button takes effect. Is there a way to have AVAudioPlayer turn off instantly upon clicking it's button in the options scene?

I do use a custom class for playing the music that I did not write. So I don't completely understand how it works. Here is the method I use inside MyScene to activate the AVAudioPlayer:

```
-(void)musicPlayer
{
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; //"Activate" defaults.
    music = [defaults boolForKey:@"MusicButtonKEY"]; //Then assign that defaults to a BOOL (music in this case).
    if (music == YES) //Check what defaults BOOL key value was set to & act accordingly to that.
    {
        [self.audioController tryPlayMusic]; //tryPlayMusic is a method from AudioController class.
        NSLog(@"Music playing");

    }
    else /*if (music == NO)*/
    {
       [self.audioController stopPlayingMusic]; //stopPlayingMusic is a method from AudioController class.
       NSLog(@"Music not playing");
    }
}
```

Here is the .h & .m files of the AudioController class:
AudioController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AudioController : NSObject

-(instancetype)init;
-(void)tryPlayMusic;
-(void)stopPlayingMusic;

@end
```

AudioController.m

```
#import "AudioController.h"
@import AVFoundation;

@interface AudioController () <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioSession *audioSession;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusicPlayer;
@property (assign) BOOL backgroundMusicPlaying;
@property (assign) BOOL backgroundMusicInterrupted;

@end

@implementation AudioController

#pragma mark - Public

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self configureAudioSession];
        [self configureAudioPlayer];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)tryPlayMusic
{
    //If background music or other music is already playing, nothing more to do here
    if (self.backgroundMusicPlaying || [self.audioSession isOtherAudioPlaying])
    {
        return;
    }

    // Play background music if no other music is playing and we aren't playing already
    //Note: prepareToPlay preloads the music file and can help avoid latency. If you don't
    //call it, then it is called anyway implicitly as a result of [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    //It can be worthwhile to call prepareToPlay as soon as possible so as to avoid needless
    //delay when playing a sound later on.
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    self.backgroundMusicPlaying = YES;
}


-(void)stopPlayingMusic
{
    if (self.backgroundMusicPlaying == YES)
    {
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer stop];
        self.backgroundMusicPlaying = NO;
    }
}


#pragma mark - Private

-(void)configureAudioSession
{
    //Implicit initialization of audio session.
    self.audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    //Set category of audio session
    //See handy chart on pg. 46 of the Audio Session Programming Guide for what the categories mean
    //Not absolutely required in this example, but good to get into the habit of doing
    //See pg. 10 of Audio Session Programming Guide for "Why a Default Session Usually Isn't What You Want"

    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    if ([self.audioSession isOtherAudioPlaying])
    { //Mix sound effects with music already playing
        [self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:&setCategoryError];
        self.backgroundMusicPlaying = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&setCategoryError];
    }
    if (setCategoryError)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error setting category! %ld", (long)[setCategoryError code]);
    }
}


-(void)configureAudioPlayer
{
    //Create audio player with background music.
    NSString *backgroundMusicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ThemeA" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *backgroundMusicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundMusicPath];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:nil];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer.delegate = self;  //We need this so we can restart after interruptions
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;  //Negative number means loop forever
}


#pragma mark - AVAudioPlayerDelegate methods

-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
{
    //It is often not necessary to implement this method since by the time
    //this method is called, the sound has already stopped. You don't need to
    //stop it yourself.
    //In this case the backgroundMusicPlaying flag could be used in any
    //other portion of the code that needs to know if your music is playing.

    self.backgroundMusicInterrupted = YES;
    self.backgroundMusicPlaying = NO;
}


-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player withOptions:(NSUInteger)flag
{
    //Since this method is only called if music was previously interrupted, you know that the music has stopped playing & can now be resumed.
      [self tryPlayMusic];
      self.backgroundMusicInterrupted = NO;
}

@end
```

Here is the button code from OptionsScene:

```
#import "OptionsScene.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


BOOL soundON;
BOOL musicON;

@interface OptionsScene ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) AGSpriteButton *AGSoundButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AGSpriteButton *AGMusicButton;

@end


@implementation OptionsScene
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;

}


-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    self = [super initWithSize:size];
    {
        defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        [self background]; //Won't show code for this method since it just loads the background.

        //Background music & sound dispatched once to get things going in this scene so to speak.
        static dispatch_once_t onceOS;
        dispatch_once(&onceOS, ^ {
            //Code to run once
            soundON = YES;
            musicON = YES;

            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"SoundButtonKEY"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            self.AGSoundButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxYES"];
            NSLog(@"SOUND switched to ON");

            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"MusicButtonKEY"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            self.AGMusicButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxYES"];
            NSLog(@"MUSIC switched to ON");
        });
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{

}


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    //Sound button.
    self.AGSoundButton = [AGSpriteButton buttonWithImageNamed:@"checkboxYES"];
    self.AGSoundButton.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2 + 50, self.size.height/2 + 70);
    self.AGSoundButton.zPosition = 2.2;
    [self.AGSoundButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(soundInit) withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.size.width + 230, self.size.height/2 + 3)] forControlEvent:AGButtonControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addChild:self.AGSoundButton];

    //Music button.
    self.AGMusicButton = [AGSpriteButton buttonWithImageNamed:@"checkboxYES"];
    self.AGMusicButton.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2 + 50, self.size.height/2 + 10);
    self.AGMusicButton.zPosition = 2.2;
    [self.AGMusicButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(musicInit) withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.size.width + 230, self.size.height/2 + 3)] forControlEvent:AGButtonControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addChild:self.AGMusicButton];


    //Call upon the saved BOOL/Button positions from their respective key's.
    BOOL soundDefaults = [defaults boolForKey:@"SoundButtonKEY"];
    BOOL musicDefaults = [defaults boolForKey:@"MusicButtonKEY"];


    //Sound button retrieval.
    if (soundDefaults == YES)
    {
        self.AGSoundButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxYES"];
        NSLog(@"Sound is ON");
    }
    if (soundDefaults == NO)
    {
        self.AGSoundButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxNO"];
        NSLog(@"Sound is OFF");
    }

    //Music button retrieval.
    if (musicDefaults == YES)
    {
        self.AGMusicButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxYES"];
        NSLog(@"Music is ON");
    }
    if (musicDefaults == NO)
    {
        self.AGMusicButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxNO"];
        NSLog(@"Music is OFF");
    }
}


//Sound button switch ON/OFF.
-(void)soundInit
{
    if (soundON == YES)
    {
        soundON = NO;
        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"SoundButtonKEY"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        self.AGSoundButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxNO"];
        NSLog(@"SOUND switched to OFF");
    }
    else /*if (soundON == NO)*/
    {
        soundON = YES;
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"SoundButtonKEY"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        self.AGSoundButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxYES"];
        NSLog(@"SOUND switched to ON");
    }
}


//Music button switch ON/OFF.
-(void)musicInit
{
    if (musicON == YES)
    {
        musicON = NO;
        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"MusicButtonKEY"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        self.AGMusicButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxNO"];
        NSLog(@"MUSIC switched to OFF");
    }
    else /*if (musicON == NO)*/
    {
        musicON = YES;
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"MusicButtonKEY"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        self.AGMusicButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"checkboxYES"];
        NSLog(@"MUSIC switched to ON");
    }
}


//Brings back to GameScene. Called by a 3rd button that I didn't bother including in this code. It doesn't really matter.
-(void)backToGame
{
    NSLog(@"Going back");

    [defaults synchronize]; //Save button states, just in case, before leaving scene.

    //Brings back to game scene.
    MyScene *firstScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:firstScene];
}

@end
```

Really hope this helps with the details.

Comment: Does stopPlayingMusic execute? Is backgroundMusicPlaying == YES at that time? Is self.backgroundMusicPlayer non-nil at that time? Set a breakpoint and find out.

Comment: Please show the code of the music button, and where do you call the `musicPlayer` method? My guess is that something is wrong with the way you set the music `BOOL` key, or you are not calling the `musicPlayer` method in the right place, so it only get executed once you relaunch the app, and the `music` variable is getting its value from the `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: I edited my post to show where the music button is called. musicPlayer is called by a method called "tryPlayMusic" from a separate class called AudioController inside MyScene (found it online - it solved my issue with song playing an extra track of it self every time I would go to the OptionsScene from MyScene).

Comment: As for the options screen, the music doesn't stop when you press the button because the button only sets `BOOL` to be `YES` or `NO`, but doesn't actually do anything about stopping or starting the music. According to your code `tryPlayMusic` is called by `musicPlayer`, and not the other way around as your comment suggests. Where in the Main Game Scene code do you call musicPlayer? try putting it in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I really should stop coding after work, late at night. It seems even basic logic doesn't seem to sprout. I looked over my code & it was some pathetic-a** sh*t. I fixed it up now.